# Why is sharing the mutable internals of immutable objects a good idea?

Tags: java, immutability, effective-java

I'm reading Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" and have two questions. Bloch states the following.

> Not only can you share immutable objects, but they can share their internals.

He then proceeds to give an example with one instance of `BigInteger` sharing its magnitude array with another `BigInteger` instance. My first question is: doesn't this violate the rule that Bloch laid out earlier, i.e.

> Ensure exclusive access to mutable components.

As an example of how sharing mutable internals could be problematic, it seems to me that if two instances `sample1` and `sample2` of the same class can share their internals then you could have the following.

```java
public final class Sample {

    private final int[] field1;
    private final int[] field2;

    public Sample(int[] field1, int[] field2) {
        this.field1 = field2;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public Sample(int[] field1, Sample sampleForField2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleForField2.field2.length; i++) {
            sampleForField2.field2[i] += 1;
        }
        this.field2 = sampleForField2.field2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample sample1 = new Sample(new int[]{0, 1}, new int[]{10, 11});
        Sample sample2 = new Sample(new int[]{20, 21}, sample1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sample1.field2));
    }

}
```

In the example above, `a` is able to share its internals with `b` via the constructor `public Sample(int[] field1, Sample sampleForField2)`. This leads to aliasing, causing `sample1`'s `field2` value to be `{11, 12}`.

Thus, my second question is: wouldn't sharing mutable internals between instances break immutability?

Comment: In my oppinion, it is not a good idea to share mutable internals of immutables. The only exception is if you can somehow guarantee that neither instance ever mutates any of its mutable compoinents (which is probably what Josh meant). Problem here is that in Java, you cannot enforce immutability on things like arrays.

Comment: BigInteger is immutable. So its internal magnitude array never changes. So sharing it with another, immutable Integer, that guarantees to never change its magnitude, is not a problem. BigInteger doesn't share its magnitude with unknown objects. It shares it with other instances of BigInteger, which guarantees the immutability of the magnitude.

Comment: What JB said is correct.  Even though the internal array is "mutable", it is in fact never changed.  This means it's really immutable (combined with some other rules in Java about synchronization and happens-before).  So even though that "mutable internal" looks mutable, it actually isn't.  That's why it's OK to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fine to share the internals of an immutable object, provided that you expose the internals of the object in an immutable way.

For example:

```
public class ImmutableObj {

  private final String[] internals;

  public ImmutableObj(String[] strings) {
    internals = Arrays.copyOf(strings, strings.length);
  }

  public String[] getInternals() {
    // return a copy of the internal state, since arrays
    // do not offer an immutable view
    return Arrays.copyOf(internals, internals.length);
  }
}
```

Arrays are an inefficient example, but it it still possible. A much more performant thing to do would be storing/exposing the internal state as some sort of `Collection<String>` so you can set the internals to an unmodifiable object to begin with:

```
public class ImmutableObj {

  // Simply make this public instead of getter since it is read-only
  public final List<String> internals;

  public ImmutableObj(String[] strings) {
    internals = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(strings));
  }

}
```

Comment: Note the OP is talking about sharing internal state (the "mutable" array) with other objects of the same class.  That's not really the same thing as exposing the internals publicly to any class, as you have here.

Comment: yea, I mainly focused on answering the first question. The second question was answered by JB Nizet in the comments